# AppBarLayout & NestedScrollView with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

Here is video that describes my problem: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1fcDbL1kcI&feature=youtu.be)

Current layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        ...

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`View` to `AppBarLayout` adds dynamically while execution.
When I scroll to the top of `ScrollView` and then update `NestedScrollView` & `AppBarLayout` content, everything works as it should. But when I scroll down and then trying to update content, `AppBarLayout` broken before I scroll to the top of `NestedScrollView`.

Scroll to the top of `NestedScrollView` before updating `NestedScrollView` & `AppBarLayout` with this method does not help:

```
public void scrollContentToTop() {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null) {
        behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, null, 0, 0, true);
    }
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution. Before updating `NestedScrollView` & `AppBarLayout` just call `setExpanded()` on your `AppBarLayout`

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, false);
```

Comment: If I call setExpanded(true, false), the appbar layout stays expanded, it's not getting collapsed when the content scrolls.